# I want to call a class object, being the class name a given parameter

Tags: php, parameters, class

I want to do something like this: (in php)

```
$a = "class_name1";    
$b = "class_name2";
$object1 = new $a;
$object2 = new $b
```

is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but what kind of a question is this? Try it out yourself...

Comment: funny, as the exact same code would work for you if you tried it :-)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

```
class A {
   public function foo(){
       echo 'bar';
   } 
}

$a = 'A';
$object = new $a();
$object->foo();
```

outputs

```
bar
```

---

**You can test such things by yourself very fast on [codepad](http://codepad.org/).**